# Calling jQuery's .ajax() from an eventHandler in c# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

In the code behind (`upload.aspx`) I have an event that returns the number of bytes being streamed; and as I debug it, it works fine. I wanted to reflect the numbers returned from the event-handler on a progress bar and this is where I got lost. I tried using jQuery's .ajax() function. this is how I implemented it:

In the EventHandler in my code behind I added this code to call the .ajax() function:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UpdateProgress", "<script type='text/javascript'>updateProgress();</script>");
```

My plan is whenever the eventHandler function changes the values of bytes being streamed it calls the javascript function "updateProgress()"

The .ajax() function "UpdateProgress()" is as:

```
function updateProgress() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {

                $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", msg.d);

            }
        });
    }
```

I made sure that the function GetData() is [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] and that it is static as well. so the workflow of what I am trying to implement is as: 
 - Click On Upload button
 - The Behind code starts executing and EventHandler triggers
 - The EventHandler calls .ajax() function
 - The .ajax() function retrieves the bytes being streamed and updates progress bar.

When I ran the code; all runs well except that the .ajax() is only executed when upload is finished (and progress bar also updates only when finished upload); even though I call .ajax() function every time in the eventHandler function as reflected above...

What am I doing wrong? Am I thinking of this right? is there anything else I should add maybe an updatePanel or something?

Comment: What does `upload.aspx/GetData` returns?

Comment: It return an int; it is as: 
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static int GetData()
    { 
        return Convert.ToInt32(byteStreamed);
    }

Comment: have you set the default value of the progress bar to zero at the beginning? Like this `$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });`

Comment: I did yes in the $(document).ready(function () {
             
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
            
        });

Answer (score 1):

Try this once:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 0
});

$("#btnUpload").click(function() {
    var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 250);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.aspx/GetData",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", 100);
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

function updateProgress() {
    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
    if (value < 100) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", value + 1);
    }
}​
```

Comment: Thank you for finding the time...However I added alert(msg) in the success; a popup with "object Object" shows after I click "ok" the progress bar fills 100% and the code behind (triggered from btnUpload_Click) does not fire..any thoughts?

Comment: Here is something else that might ring some bells maybe; when I comment out the .ajax() function the code behind (that upload) works fine, when I recomment the .ajax() the same case described earlier happens (code behind does not fire up and bar 100% with a popup of [object Object])

Comment: Remove the `return false;` and try again

Comment: Thanks; your answer was very helpful; I learnt from it; It actually works; the only issue is that the progress bar is not updated based on the value changed in the eventHandler; if the file was large the progress bar fills up and the upload is still going on...any thought on how I could tackle this? should I maybe call `var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 250);` from within .ajax()?